# Ruby | Cucumber: Refactoring my Transform

Tags: ruby, cucumber, integration-testing

I wrote a transform to capture one of the following words: "first", "second", "third", or "fourth" representing quarters of a year. Here's what I wrote, I was hoping there might be a much simpler way of doing this. Any thoughts?

```
CAPTURE_QUARTER = Transform /^(first|second|third|fourth)$/ do |quarter|
  case quarter
    when 'first'
      1
    when 'second'
      2
    when 'third'
      3
    when 'fourth'
      4
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Possible solution:

```
CAPTURE_QUARTER = Transform /^(first|second|third|fourth)$/ do |quarter|
  {first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4}[quarter.to_sym]
end
```

Thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest you yet another way of doing that:

```
quarters = {first: 1, second: 2, third: 3, fourth: 4}
CAPTURE_QUARTER = Transform /^(first|second|third|fourth)$/ do |quarter|
  quarters[quarter.to_sym]
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have `quarter[0]`, isn't quarter just a string?

Comment: Yep, you're right. Sorry for stupid typo :) I've updated my post

Comment: We both came up with the same solution, haha :) I'll mark yours as an answer, as it is indeed much shorter. The case statement seems to have more readability to it, but they both certainly work.